# Django: testing with login_required

Tags: django

I am trying to test a post request on a view which has login_required.

if i run this in the shell django:

```
Client().post('/recipes/', {'name' : 'Matar Cauliflower ', 'mass_unit' : '', 'mass_quantity' : '', 'volume_unit' : '1', 'volume_quantity' : '50', 'pieces_unit' : '', 'pieces_quantity' : ''},follow=True).status_code
```

I get:

```
<HttpResponseRedirect status_code=302, "text/html; charset=utf-8", url="/login/?next=/recipes/">
```

How to pass the login credentials are tell that a user is logged in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For use in unit testing, you can create a test user (which will be deleted after `manage.py test` finishes running), and provide its credentials to [the test client's login() method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.login).

Or you can call that `login()` method with valid credentials for a user you know exists. You could also use the `force_login()` method further down that documentation page, but for testing the best practice is to have your tests create a test-only user and log in as that user.